# How to sort array containing objects such as abc, abc1, abc2, abc10, xyz112

Tags: objective-c, sorting

Can anyone please suggest how to sort array containing objects such as:

```
    "abd",
    "kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk",
    "Take 1",
    "Take 10",
    "Take 11",
    "Take 12",
    "Take 13",
    "Take 14",
    "Take 15",
    "Take 16",
    "Take 17",
    "Take 18",
    "Take 2",
    "Take 4",
    "Take 5",
    "Take 6",
    "Take 8"
```

Sort the array in ascending order so that "Take 2" comes after "Take 1".

Comment: ...and `"Take 8"` comes before `"Take 10"`, I assume?

Comment: Yes..."Take 8" should come before "Take 10"

Answer (score 1):

You could use the sort selector on an array:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [yourArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

Comment: actually this is not enough you need some extra logic to take in account the number - so you will need to write your own comparison method instead